# GWT Button Long mouse press

Tags: java, gwt

I am making a input spinner component. It's almost working, I just was unable to get long mouse click in the up and down buttons.

Is it possible? If yes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out http://code.google.com/p/gwt-incubator-1-5-wiki/wiki/Spinner
It has the feature you're looking for. You can either use the component it self or see how it implements the feature

Comment: i want to know how to get the long mouse press event, but, thanks anyway.

Comment: Well there is no such event "long mouse press event", you have to implement it using a timer ... there is an example in Spinner.java